# How should I indicate that a button or input is disabled in a dark theme?

Tags: gui-design, themes

As is the web standard, disabled inputs become "grayed out", getting a little darker and sometimes less opaque:

[image: enabled buttons and input]
[image: disabled buttons and input]

So my question is how to replicate this in dark mode. This is how it looks when they're enabled:

[image: enabled buttons and input - dark mode]

And the options are to make them either lighter (to mimic them being grayed out) or darker (because that's what happens in light mode) when disabling:

[image: disabled buttons and input option 1 - dark mode]
[image: disabled buttons and input option 2 - dark mode]

Is there an existing pattern for this?

Answer (score 6):

Disabled buttons are usually a play on contrast/opacity.

Here is MUI light theme:

[image: A light theme showing buttons in various states]

And here is their dark theme:

[image: A dark theme showing buttons in various states]

This library follows Google's Material Design guidelines and you can have a look at the dark/light styling of many UI components in both light and dark theme (see toggle button at the app bar right side):

https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Answer (score 5):

A rule of thumb is to [reduce the button's opacity](https://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-you-shouldnt-gray-out-disabled-buttons/) vs. graying out.

> When the disabled button is transparent, users can see some semblance
>   of the button in its enabled state. Although the button is faded out,
>   some color still bleeds through for recognition. As the disabled
>   button transitions to an enabled state, its new appearance is what
>   they expect.
>
> A transparent button ... blends into the background more, while a gray
>   one stands out in the foreground (unless the background is gray).
>   Foreground elements are more noticeable, which means users are more
>   likely to click a gray disabled button. When they do, they’ll wonder
>   why it’s not doing anything.
>
> Another issue with gray buttons is that it’s easy for users to mistake
>   them for secondary actions. Gray is often used to communicate a low
>   priority button (e.g., cancel buttons). When they see a gray button,
>   they won’t know for sure if it’s disabled unless they click it. This
>   uncertainty and unpredictability is not an optimal user experience.

Answer (score 1):

A way to show the inactive state is to keep the background color unchanged but change the text color by making it darker.

Visual studio dark theme does this in the menu:
[image: visual studio dark theme menu]

Answer (score 1):

Disabling a control doesn't make it *darker* per se, it *reduces its contrast*.

The desired effect is not to make a disabled control look gray for the sake of being gray, it's to make it *less prominent* when compared to enabled controls.